# Burninate [3rd-party-controls]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The tag [3rd-party-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party-controls) is not useful. A lot of the questions can be closed with the *recommendation* reason, and otherwise it's probably a meta tag.

Can we close all off-topic questions under this tag, and then maybe in a few days remove the tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a part of this:

- I retagged the good questions.
- I did not retag the close-worthy questions and the questions I wasn't 100% sure about. These still have the [3rd-party-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party-controls) tag to make it easy to find them for review.
- I did not retag the on hold/closed questions in case they should be deleted.

Stats after the first cleanup (30 Oct 2014, 19:00 UTC):

- About 10 questions are retagged.
- 11 questions in the [3rd-party-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party-controls) tag are on hold.
- 13 questions in the [3rd-party-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party-controls) tag are still open.

**Update:** Now the last question in [3rd-party-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party-controls) has been closed, I removed the tag from the 10 questions who still had it. This tag has been burninated!

[image: Burninated]