# Cleaning up after the [third-party] and such like

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

We've got a [3rd-party-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party-library) tag floating around, which has this wonderfully descriptive message as its tagline:

> This tag has been deprecated because it lacks discriminating power. **Do not use it**, use a tag specific to the 3rd party library instead.

Let's burninate it and teach them to clean up after their parties.

In the same vein, there's the [third-party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/third-party) and [3rd-party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party) tags floating around too.  I'd propose that it gets looked at and cleaned up a bit, since we're in the same neck of the woods (if there are things that can be salvaged, then that's fine).

Comment: toast that [third-party]

Comment: Before you know it there's a [fourth-party], [fifth-party] etc etc. We can't have that - burninate ASAP I'd say!

Comment: Sillyness aside, searching for "Party" in the tags section gives a few related burnination candidates IMHO.

Comment: What about the [3rd-party] ?

Comment: What a 3rd party is depends on the context of the person who asks it. I think it adds no value to a question (as opposed to, say, [spring] or [angular]). I'd agree to burninate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that there are a lot of other tags and work done on this so far.

First of all, there was [this effort from 10 months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275680/burninate-3rd-party-controls?rq=1), though I agree this request is more broad.

Here are the relevant tags:

- <del>[third-party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/third-party) - 126 questions **done**</del>
- <del>[external-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/external-library) - 106 questions</del> **done**
- <del>[3rd-party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party) - 111 questions</del> **done**
- <del>[third-party-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/third-party-code) - 76 questions</del> **done**
- <del>[third-party-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/third-party-api) - 68 questions</del> **done**
- <del>[third-party-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/third-party-controls) - 50 questions</del> **done**
- <del>[third-party-cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/third-party-cookie) - 16 questions</del> **done**
- [3rd-party-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party-library) - 0 questions **done**

All of these tags should probably go, but we shouldn't just clean up one of them and ignore the others as in the effort from 10 months ago, otherwise this will keep happening again and again.

#### Plan of attack:

If you want to volunteer to help, drop by the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room to check in, introduce yourself, and get connected with the team.

1. Review open questions in each targeted tag. Edit & remove offending tag(s) from any questions that merit retention. Make any other reasonable question improvements. Pay special attention to adding tags for referenced "third-party" thingamabobs.
2. Questions that should be closed and deleted should have offending tag(s) replaced with [third-party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/third-party), to simplify their death-watch. (If you find closed questions that will be automatically deleted, leave them be.)
3. Questions that are closed as duplicates and should be retained as markers should have all offending tags removed.

#### Activity links:

- [third-party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/third-party) <s>[Close vote review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=3rd-party+third-party).</s>
- Questions requiring delete votes: [Closed Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5b*-party*%5d%20or%20%5bexternal-library%5d%20closed%3ayes)

### Locked posts

<s>[These questions require a moderator to burn](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5b*-party*%5d%20or%20%5bexternal-library%5d%20locked%3ayes).</s>

Comment: [third-party-cookies] is the only one of those which *might* be useful. At least I need a bit more convincing it isn't.

Comment: @Deduplicator I thought the same thing, but at 16 questions, it could probably just be merged into [tag:cookies].

Comment: There is a notion of "third-party JavaScript" with very specific meaning (see http://thirdpartyjs.com/ ). I think a new tag should be introduced for it, after which it can be assigned to many questions with the tags [javascript] + one from the list above.

Comment: @thorn Do you have some sense of how many of these tags are about that?

Comment: I took a look at [javascript]+[third-party] and [javascript]+[third-party-code]. Around 25% of the questions are about *"independent client code executing on a publisher's website, but served from a remote web address"*. What's good about the [third-party-javascript] tag is that it would have this well-defined meaning, and thus the discriminating power.

Comment: @thorn: If it's a reference to that book, it doesn't deserve a tag. Whether using code on other sites deserves a tag for js, I'm not sure.

Comment: It's a reference to the book as much as the [design-patterns] tag is a reference to the you-know-what book. When one develops something to be embedded on other sites, they're bound to face a number of very specific issues a developer normally doesn't care about. So why not systematize this knowledge under its own tag?

Comment: @Mog: [external-library] is nearly reasonable. Though most look like exactly the same cruft, and anyway they should be tagged [jni] or whatever the specific ffi is called.

Comment: This answer has spawned another [meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307009/189134)

Comment: Looks like in that melee, the entirety of [tag:third-party] was made victim to a mass purge.  There were ~110 by the time I had wrapped up for the night, so it seems like this is good to go.  I'll hold off editing this until sometime again tomorrow GMT, since someone could pop up and ask yet another question tagged with it.

Comment: If this isn't supposed to happen anymore, maybe this answer should be edited/deleted??

Comment: Just follow the algorithm and down vote it to oblivion.  -- Why we can't have good things.  Someone always wants to play god.

Comment: This edit: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/303695/51 was considered harmful.  Telling people to downvote answers because you want to auto-delete the questions ... doesn't seem kosher.