# Clean-up by downvoting? A ridiculous user experience

Tags: discussion, downvotes, burninate-system

I was wondering how I suddenly got <s>5</s> 6 downvotes on a 5-year-old, and well-upvoted [answer (10k link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2986900/165500) [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ1e3.png). After some hunting around...

> There are just a few questions & answers needing to be voted down to 0 for automatic removal:

See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/303695/55).

Seriously?

**Surely there is a better way of doing this?**

This kind of thing does *not* come across well as a user of the site. At first blush it looks like malicious sockpuppetry.

Now it just looks like I'm being penalized for some long-after-the-fact policy change, relating to a posting (i.e.: the question) that wasn't even mine.

---

[image: downvotes]

EDIT: Ha. Ha. Very funny:

[image: Yes you are very clever]

---

EDIT: I am not the only one affected by this:

> Answered 4 years ago, then 2 downvotes in 2 days... weird... but why?

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775169/developer-class-with-one-or-more-expertises/30775317#comment53498035_30775317). That comment is 18 hours old at time of writing. On an answer that had just *two* upvotes.

Comment: You even have the ability to vote to delete questions yourself, which the voters plainly ignored. Fun times.

Comment: OK, I put the question and the answers out of their misery.

Comment: Oh wow. Am I seeing things? Seconds before I deleted the question, every one of the voters removed their downvotes one by one.

Comment: No they didn't - I was curious about the number of delete votes that *would've* been required to remove the question without downvotes, and decided to take the lazy route to calculate it... At which point you made sure I had to do it the hard way anyway. @BoltClock

Comment: @Shog9: Oh. oops

Comment: The *answer* probably shouldn't have been downvoted, but the *question* surely was being targeted for autoremoval, which in this case, might just be faster with 3 others voting for its deletion.

Comment: ITT, Shog has the ability to clear votes from a post.

Comment: @Mysticial: Shhhhhh! Don't let the revenge downvoters hear you.

Comment: My account is glitched and I can actually remove upvotes from my posts. But for that you have to upvote it and let the upvote sit for a day. Promise.

Comment: The day when the legions of help vampires descend on Shog begging him to remove downvotes from their questions is the day I will die on the floor laughing.

Comment: Regardless of the particular circumstances of my post, hopefully you guys can figure out a better system for the next poor sap. Because (if I understand what was *supposed* to happen correctly) unless there's enough folks to downvote-to-oblivion all at once, those downvotes just sit there for *weeks*. And so the people who cop it the worst are going to be the people with *good* questions/answers.

Comment: I'm not so sure I see a solution to it.  Yes, in this case there was some collateral damage (and those downvotes seem to have been spirited away anyhow), but given the nature of burnination, you get people downvoting *everything* about a question that comes up in a request, even if it's not deserved.  You can't really stop people from downvoting answers for any arbitrary reason.

Comment: @Mysticial: I bet half of the vamps don't even notice, much less care.

Comment: @Makoto: The linked answer appears to be saying that the answers have to be downvoted along with the questions to accelerate the auto-deletion process, so the votes appear to be quite focused - there is no collateral.

Comment: Breaking news: Mysticial found dead of laughter, four years in the past. Time-travelling vote-whiners blamed.

Comment: I would have thought *at least* that before doing this, someone would post a comment to the answer saying "Hey, this question is off-topic but this answer is keeping the Roomba from doing its job. Would you delete it please?" The answer wasn't accepted, so you'd be able to do so. If someone were reluctant to delete an upvoted answer on an off-topic question, *then* perhaps look for the next way to address the situation. Starting off by just downvoting is just asinine, as it means the answerer (you) needs to go figure what the *&$# is happening. The courtesy fail on this is massive.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Surprised no one has retorted with "voters are not obligated to comment" or "there is no such thing as courtesy or humanness on Stack Overflow" yet.

Comment: Of course, you're not the only one affected. I had this several times too, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13766551/1741542, http://stackoverflow.com/q/15390367/1741542, http://stackoverflow.com/q/14167082/1741542. I guess, you will find a lot more of this kind of *serial downvoting*, if you really want to invest your time.

Comment: Here is the edit where downvoting answers was suggested: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/303695/51 it was 3 days ago.  Prior to that, questions where being downvoted, with no encouragement of downvoting answers.

Comment: Of course, downvoting-to-delete questions will still have the same ridiculous user experience. The only thing you can really say is that you are *less* likely to hit "good" posts if you only hit questions. Also keep in mind that many of these questions are old -- they may have been perfectly ok at the time.

Comment: @AndrewRussell - Thanks for bringing this up, because it is important. Users like yourself who create useful content by answering questions, solving problems, and helping other users are essential to the success here. Hopefully your negative experience leads to some change, and also does not prevent you from contributing in the future. We need more contributors like you here.

Comment: I thought that was done simply because "someone dared to associate with something I don't like - downvote". You mean that there's an actual, grounded in site mechanics, reason that people downvote answers to question they don't like? TIL

Answer (score 183):

Yeah... This is unacceptable.

If you're downvoting questions because they're lazy / poorly-written / useless, more power to you.

If you're downvoting *answers* because they're lazy / poorly-written / wrong / useless, good on ya.

But blindly downvoting answers to avoid... retagging? That's just wrong. Voting to delete? The number of votes required to delete questions is capped at 10 - but in this case it would've only required three. Triggering automatic deletion?

### This is why we can't have nice things

...Ah. An unfortunate side-effect of [the current rules for automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) are that they don't take into account *when* downvotes are cast. A question's answers can sit at +7 for years, but as soon as they get downvoted to <= 0 the question **immediately** qualifies for auto-deletion under one or more criteria. No need for 10K privileges, no rationing your delete votes, no concerns about having your name attached to the moderation you're doing...

Policing voting isn't really a solution here; it's hard, ethically-grey, and doesn't scale. If folks are doing this awkward dance as a more convenient way of voting to delete, we really only have two choices:

1. Make voting to delete more convenient
2. Make downvoting answers as a proxy for voting to delete questions less convenient

Guessing that giving folks with 125 rep the ability to delete questions with upvoted answers ain't gonna fly, so that just leaves #2: make questions with recent voting activity (on the question or answers) ineligible for auto-deletion for some hefty period of time.

Comment: How long until people start piling on their downvotes now so they can delete this question later?

Comment: "but in this case it would've only required three" And I gather one of the *answerers*, in this case the OP of said meta question, would have been more than eager to contribute taking into account the policy changes that made this question now off-topic.

Comment: Right. So instead of needing to find one other person to vote to delete, someone dug up 5 other people to downvote. Some crazy, crazy unintended consequences here...

Comment: Would basing the auto-delete criteria on a lack of upvotes instead of only the score work? So instead of score <= 0 we have something like score <=0 and upvotes <= 1 (or higher). I suspect this wouldn't change anything in the vast majority of cases, but it might prevent people from gaming the system to delete questions with upvoted answers.

Comment: 3. Make tag burnination an SE staff duty like it used to be.

Comment: [What's the update on this?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt)

Comment: @MadScientist has the best idea. But 1 upvote received on a post to prevent roomba is too strict. Be fine with adding roomba rule that no single post on the the question (including the question) have more than 3 upvotes. Shog's idea of keeping them ineligible for "hefty time" would just hurt helpful moderation taken by this roomba route and probably stop the this particular practice all together. It's a fact that not enough stuff gets deleted quick enough or at all, so increasing time is not way to go. Simple additional roomba rule of "can not have received > 3 upvotes on single post" is good

Comment: As one of the users (perhaps THE user?) called a "DICK", Shog, I'm chastised - and very willing to change - but also offended. The fact that the OP was able to point at a meta post discussing open community actions supporting clean-up of off-topic tags illustrates a desire to engage and conform with community views. Interesting to note that there was not even one comment on that post (or other similar burnination posts) to discuss "feeding the Roomba". Such conversation would have been most constructive before the name-calling.

Comment: I explicitly avoided calling anyone out, @Mogsdad. The behavior is the problem, not the people - that the system unintentionally encourages this behavior is the problem I propose to address. Note that no one owning these answers can see who downvoted them (much less *why*) - they can't exactly begin a conversation about "feeding the Roomba" unless someone lets them know that's what was happening.

Comment: Still do that, @Hans... But the problem with most of these burnination requests isn't the tags themselves, it's the questions in them - if getting rid of the tag means getting rid of all the questions, that's something that should involve public collaboration.

Comment: I've run a couple ad-hoc tests using variations on the proposed criteria, @durron597 - they've gone pretty well. But the big open question is... Actually, this. How will increasing auto-deletion alter folks' behavior? How *should* it?

Comment: @Shog9 You could argue that if more stuff were automatically deleted, then this sort of behavior would be far less necessary. In this case, the people involved were looking to help the site, not help themselves or prank others.

Comment: Which brings me back to #1 above, @durron597: this is a horribly awkward way of marking things for deletion, and there's a [delete] link *right on the page* - if everyone who'd downvoted had voted to delete (and most of them *could* have done so), it'd still have taken fewer votes and less time than it did... So what motivated the Rube Goldberg method?

Comment: @Shog9 In the case of [tag:third-party] there were over 500 posts. In the case of [tag:source] or [tag:source-code] there were close to 2000. We only get so many delete votes per day, but we get a lot more downvotes per day. Plus people who don't have 10k want to help delete garbage. You say yourself that closure is just a precursor to deletion anyway... [requests like this one haven't gotten a staff response](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250840/tags-that-only-exist-on-locked-questions-should-we-treat-these-the-same-as-tags).

Comment: Either closed questions should all eventually head down the trash chute or they shouldn't. [Either closing is the precursor to deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221858/revisiting-free-downvotes-on-questions/221880#221880), or it isn't. When we try to stem the tide of garbage by preventing people from using off topic tags, we end up using any and all means available to us. The solution isn't to take away that power, the solution is to isolate the actual problem and change the system to address *that*. Feel free to ping me in SOCVR.

Comment: You're missing my point here, @durron597. There are well-defined paths to take questions from closure to deletion, and from closure to reopening - therefore closure serves its purpose as a sort of limbo. Expecting a question that takes years to be closed to be deleted in days is unrealistic; surely there should be a time for review, else what is the point? 3000 questions require at most 9000 delete votes, and in practice a lot fewer due to autodeletion; delete votes do not age away.

Comment: @Shog9 It doesn't take years for it to be closed because people thought it should be open, it took years for it to be closed because on one was looking at it and because close votes age away. Currently it takes two days to vote to delete the question anyway; perhaps you are suggesting that the two day period should be longer?

Comment: Not really true, @durron597. The blanket prohibition on tool-rec questions is relatively new in terms of SO history; a *lot* of the rules and standards now in place arose organically over the course of years. Folks asked and answered questions in good faith... Then things changed. The 5-yr-old question that motivated this never had a single downvote or close vote before this month. [I'm in chat, btw](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)

Comment: unacceptable, yeah sure. You got to be f#cking kidding. Fastest-gun "games" polluting site with garbage are acceptable. Duplicate answers to popular questions are acceptable. Lemming upvotes to hot questions are not just acceptable - encouraged. Voting down answers to off-topic questions that barely managed to scrape handful votes in several years is... not. Yeah that's the way to go... off the top results in web search

Comment: So if you check the revision history, you'll see I didn't actually write "unacceptable" @gnat... Not that it probably helps your mood any. Unacceptable works just as well: given the mods currently spend a ridiculous amount of time policing rings of people who *upvote* posts for fraudulent ends, it's awful hard to argue this should be encouraged.

Comment: The impression that I am getting from the folks behind this - after reading their chat - is that they intend to keep doing it, if at all possible (and simply 'try' to avoid doing it to +6 posts). As such, I fully support a technical solution that nerfs the roomba. Especially given the example I added to the OP, of someone with a +2 post getting weirded out by the same behaviour. -- People should also keep in mind that, to a user of the site, this kind of (pseudo-)moderation comes across as officially endorsed site policy. Most users are not well versed in what goes on in meta, myself included.

Comment: your analogy with (up)voting rings is nice. Sorta. You only forgot to mention some "minor" differences. Folks voted in question that was reviewed by five 3K users and deemed inappropriate. Voting was not personally targeted. And none of voters benefited personally (rather opposite)

Comment: @AndrewRussell Did you also read the chat between myself and Shog [in the Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4025305#4025305)? It's much more informative, and led to [this proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307068/1768232)

Comment: So... fraud is ok as long as I don't personally benefit from it? I'll let the bank know I'm check-kiting *for charity* now then, @gnat.

Comment: I 125+ rep user gangs should get less delete power, but it needs to be a lot easier to delete stuff for both 10kers (severely limited by their tiny vote allocation) and lower rep trusted users (like me with several old review badges and 5k) who can't even flag to *recommend deletion*. With all the policies made to encourage quantity over quality, there need to at least be ways to filter away the inevitable flood of crap.

Comment: The system is obviously optimized for page views, rather than helpfulness, so the S:N ratio is approaching that of a forum as popularity increases. If we want to have higher quality standards than a forum, we must not be averse to deletion like forums are.

Comment: Why don't you start by [earning the delete privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/user/2371861) before you complain about the lack of votes, @bjb. *Then* post a feature-request.

Comment: I don't think we are averse to deletion. I also agree with shog about the d̶i̶c̶k̶i̶s̶h̶n̶e̶s̶s̶  unacceptable behavior here. There was p̶e̶r̶s̶o̶n̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ targeted voting and that is the main concern. Colluding to vote, regardless of the aim of the voting, goes against the site's design. While it is important to maintain quality material, creating new quality material is more important than finding low view posts from 5 years ago. We should aim at spending time creating quality content and helping users more than we should be aimed at "attacking" users who have helped others in the past.

Comment: @Shog If I wanted to get 5k (in any reasonable amount of time), I know I'll have to contribute to the noise problem by answering crappy questions that only help OP.

Comment: @bjb568 - There are quality questions asked every day. It is *your* problem if you cannot find them. Not everything here is crap, and that is a terrible view to hold of the site.

Comment: Sure there are quality duplicates, but at least in my tags there isn't much origional quality content that I can answer. And almost always when there is, there's the FGITW problem and I can't add much information over the faster answers.

Comment: it's not [fraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraud), because fraud purpose is to "to secure unfair or unlawful **gain**". Voters gain nothing. If you want to somehow label what's going on there, try at least something... less inaccurate

Comment: Right, just so we're clear on this, it's totally ok to abuse the system and screw with other users if you have a good, selfless-sounding explanation for it when you're caught. You wanna know how many voting rings give the "we're just trying to save overlooked answers" explanation, @gnat? Reg'lr saints, those vote-ringers. *Everyone* has a story...

Comment: @gnat - Well, it is an abuse of the system and a gamification by way of collusion. That aside, I agree! There is no gain here, they are **not contributing** anything by doing this. No one gains from these activities.

Comment: no matter how you twist it, it's technically impossible to gain from this kind of voting

Comment: Oh, you wanna get *technical*? Then no, it's not impossible, @gnat - in fact, it's not even particularly uncommon for a group to use this exact technique to downvote competing answers, thus ensuring more views and more votes for those they favor without leaving an obvious trail of votes pointing back at themselves. So once again, we're back to intent: are we moderating based on patterns, or... who can tell the best story?

Comment: I knew this will pop up (congrats, you got to it sooner than I expected). This is long known as tactical / strategic downvoting and, surprise! nobody calls this fraud. System simply has got technical means to tame it from becoming too abusive (vote lock), and so should it in the case discussed here (this may be trickier to design though)

Comment: @gnat - The tool may be tactical downvoting, which is absurd in itself, but the act is deceitful, deceptive, crooked, or underhanded (all synonyms of fraud - which was used as an analogy). *"One thing I can tell you is that if you start targeting downvotes at experts who are just trying to help, you will start to drive those people away. I've already seen this in a few cases."* -Brad Larson♦ (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255861/1026459) . Tactical downvoting is not encouraged, and it is called out for abuse. Surprise! Being abusive is being deceitful, deceptive, crooked, or underhanded.

Comment: @gnat - I thought [we already covered this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255853/should-downvotes-be-used-to-punish-people-who-answer-bad-questions) recently. Your premise is flawed, and so is your baseless comment you linked. Tactical downvoting is just downvoting an answer not based on quality but based on the question; it is a strategic undertaking to impose some sort of zealous interpretation of "crap". I will take someone who is answering questions any day over the week over someone who runs around yelling "crap" and complaining about answers without actually contributing.

Comment: @gnat The bottom line is that downvoting for roomba is a bad solution to a <s>good</s> real problem. I and others did it because we were trying to address a real problem, but that doesn't mean *the act itself* was correct, and I agree with everyone else here who is saying that it wasn't. We are currently working [on solutions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307068/) to solve this problem in a different way.

Comment: @TravisJ Removal of garbage is a contribution. I'll have to show your comment your garbage man / janitor etc. and tell them that you don't think he's contributing, and he'll remind you of his lack of contribution as the garbage begins to pile up.

Comment: @durron597 - Okay, so that was really my point. There are gains if there are contributions. In this case, you could then call that fraudulent.

Comment: @durron597 I hadn't, and I've only had a skim now, but both the question and answer in the linked meta post look solid.

Answer (score 86):

Before I say anything else:

### Mea culpa.

Even though I am not one of the 6 downvotes on this answer, this is my fault. (I am the original author of that [cleanup status post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303695/1768232)). I have personally encouraged this sort of behavior in the past, been told to stop (and have personally stopped), but failed to properly educate my friends to not resort to this sort of behavior on highly upvoted answers.

As a Room owner of [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), I feel personally responsible for this behavior and I will (and have already) take steps to ensure this does not happen again.

All that said:

- No one here appears to be arguing that the question is on topic. In fact, the very first thing that happened after this Meta post was made was for the question under discussion to be mod deleted.
- When a question is deleted by the roomba, all reputation loss for the downvotes is immediately refunded.

Again, I *completely agree* that large, organized voting efforts for deletion of old questions is bad. But I *also* think that changing the roomba rules is a harsh overreaction, especially when we know **exactly** who the people are that are doing this, and groups of people doing this happen extremely infrequently. It's not many groups of people are doing this all over the site. We made a mistake here, absolutely no question. But we can fix it, @Shog already has fixed it, and we can educate the people doing it (who *do* listen) to stop doing it.

Please give me a chance to handle this on my end before making it significantly more difficult for our well intentioned cleanup efforts to proceed. [I have created a pin to begin the effort of explaining this to the users of our chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26024993#26024993).

Comment: This is a great answer, but just a quick note to one of your points: _"When a question is deleted by the roomba, all reputation loss for the downvotes is immediately refunded."_ From what I gather, the post was at +7 before this all happened, and it sounds like it was an old post. If the downvoting hadn't happened, it sounds like the post would have qualified to keep the rep from upvotes too. So just having the rep loss from downvotes being refunded is not a great thing here, because the OP loses more that way from reverted upvotes, now that the post is scored below 3.

Comment: @Kendra No, because reputation gained more than 60 days ago is preserved no matter what.

Comment: @durron597 only if the post has a score three or above when deleted. Also this doesn't consider future rep gains from the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder From http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222: `(Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained).`

Comment: FWIW, there _is_ a way to drop answers to zero without inflicting a rep loss on the answerer, but it does take 50% more voters. Let `k` be the answer's score. Give the answer `k/4` upvotes and `5k/4` downvotes. `k/4-5k/4 = -k` so the score drops to zero, and `10k/4-2*5k/4 = 0`, so the rep is unchanged. For `k%4 != 0`, give it an extra upvote so the answerer has a nett rep gain rather than a nett loss.

Comment: Actually, it might be nice to give all these answers, including the  `k%4 == 0` ones some nett rep gain: it's not the answerer's fault that their answer is attached to a question that's now deemed OT. And give them some advance notice (via a comment), in case they want to save what they may consider to be valuable content that they posted to SO in good faith.

Comment: @PM2Ring any upvotes would be lost when the question is deleted as you only keep the rep after 60 days.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Ah, right. And I guess that 60 days is a bit long for a busy clean-up squad to wait. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring WRT advance notice - There's a 4+ yr-old request for automatic notification along those lines, ["Send authors an inbox message if their question gets closed"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842). If that were implemented, the answerer in this case could have had time to take action to update the question to conform to current standards.

Comment: @Mogsdad it's likely that notifications won't work and meta will still be filled with whining. I just noticed - OP here has been watching votes going on their post [for about 10 days](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rcd7B.png) and they did nothing. All they will do is sit, wait and whie

Comment: @gnat - Speaking of whining. Why even come here and kibitz like this? You aren't even a contributor (last post was from 2013). Perhaps you should stick to the exchange you are active on instead of making broad assumptions on others. "OP" Andrew Russell is an important and frequent contributor here.

Comment: @TravisJ observe that answer discussed here is 5 years old, and that main concern of this meta discussion is about old posts. I am trying to learn here how to maintain my old posts at SO, fair enough? (on a side note, I suspect that "contribution" doesn't quite mean what you think it means)

Comment: @gnat When you say I "did nothing", what *exactly* do you expect me to do? Especially 10 days prior? A single downvote with no explanation is just noise. It seems 5 downvotes in a row is where I am actually bothered enough to poke around for the cause. --- I am certainly not here to whine. I am here to give some constructive criticism about something dumb "the site" is doing. A careful reading of the OP will reveal this (hint: what am I suggesting needs fixing?)

Comment: @AndrewRussell for those who ignore downvotes, not much can be done I'm afraid. Otherwise, there are many options. For example, to just [preserve rep points](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290370/839601), one can simply delete their old answer with score 3 or more. A solid option recently discussed over here is to edit question, improve it nd reopen. Etc

Comment: @gnat Those seem like reasonable responses where (A) the user is concerned about preserving rep, and (B) the downvotes are occurring naturally, based on the post's content. But neither of those is the case here.

Comment: @AndrewRussell as far as I know, this is considered voting on content. There are different views on when to vote and even whether to vote at all, but there also seems to be a firm consensus that this issue relates to content (is not personal). See eg [Downvoting good answers on bad questions, helpful or not?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274919/839601)

Comment: @gnat - That post was obviously the wrong one. Please see the official response to that http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255861/1026459 which is *no*, it is not helpful. It is even expanded on in another answer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255805/1026459 . If you think that is helping, you need to change the way you vote. Clearly from your voting history, these posts address behavior that you exhibit so please take some time to read and evaluate the outlook on this site.

Comment: @TravisJ you know what I like most about this question? "viewed 2685 times" notice at the sidebar. Hope it means 2K+ readers learned one more way to clean up the off-topic garbage, one more way to break [old rotten romance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/839601). Myself, I don't do _roomba voting_ at Stack Overflow but that's only because I don't have enough time for that; knowing that others do this and more of others learn to do this makes me feel really good