# Downvote in order to be able to vote to delete. Is it acceptable?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, vote-to-delete, ethics

After reaching 20K, when browsing Stack Overflow (main or meta) I sometimes encounter posts that I believe merit deletion, but the "delete" link is not available because the post is not downvoted enough. The threshold is -3 for questions and -1 for answers.

In cases like this is it ok to downvote the post with the sole intention to enable and use the "delete" link? The system has put those thresholds in place for good reasons, so is this considered an abuse in the sense that you use a privilege for a post that didn't originally meet the criteria for deletion?

I have read this post: [Clean-up by downvoting? A ridiculous user experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307009/clean-up-by-downvoting-a-ridiculous-user-experience), and the consensus is that you shouldn't organize voting rings in order to delete otherwise well received posts, but this question is different because in this case a) it is only your own vote, b) the post isn't well received (yet?).

To get the sense of the type of posts I am talking about, here are a couple of examples. They were marginally above the threshold, and I was able to vote to delete only after downvoting them: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45019614/828193) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350511/828193) (<10K links [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PmKM.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3gee.png)) **Note:** 2 was on meta.

Comment: I mean... if you feel it's worth deleting, surely it's worth downvoting.

Comment: If SE only wants you to be able to vote on posts where someone besides you has downvoted and the score is negative, then it would check for that.  Besides, it's not like you have a unilateral delete vote; you still need 3 other users to vote to delete.

Comment: No, you should only vote to delete things that you want to upvote.

Comment: Nothing is legal that is not specifically allowed. Please turn yourself in at your local disintegration kiosk for termination. Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Dupe on big meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135073/is-using-this-downvote-delete-loophole-exploitative

Comment: Downvote to allow you to delete vote? Good idea. Downvote to get Roomba to delete it for you? [Bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307009/clean-up-by-downvoting-a-ridiculous-user-experience)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The real problem here is that you haven't already downvoted.

If you think a post warrants deletion, surely it also warrants a downvote. I can kinda understand skipping that if you think it's gonna be deleted in a few minutes anyway, but if you *wouldn't* downvote a post at all were it not for your desire to delete it... Then you should probably question either your rationale for deletion, or your rationale for (not) voting.

Comment: I guess I don't downvote as much as I should, benefit of the doubt thing... But I do care about not leaving NAA and blatantly off topic posts even for a short time, as they send other users the wrong message.

Comment: Consider that downvote can prompt the author themselves to delete in some cases, thus saving everyone time.

Comment: @user000001, Sometimes, downvoting can be more effective than a delete-vote. There are [> 1,000,000 questions which Roomba will delete if downvoted once](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+answers%3A0+score%3A..0+created%3A..2017-05).  I'm not advocating going through and downvoting only to have questions deleted. But, any of those questions which do deserve to be deleted, probably also deserve a downvote, which will get them deleted. If interested, I wrote the user script: [Roomba Forecaster - When will the question be Rooma'ed? If it won't, why?](https://stackapps.com/q/7239).

Comment: To put @Makyen number on perspective, there are 13.2 million questions on the site older than 30 days. These questions may be deleted by the 365 days roomba rule, but the downvote expedites this making them eligible by the 30 days one.

Comment: @Braiam, FYI: Of those >1M questions, [564k are currently ineligible for the 365-day Roomba due to something other than time](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+answers%3A0+score%3A..0+created%3A..2016-06); most because they have >1 comment. Thus, for those 564k, it is not just expediting the process. It's changes them from being eligible for no Roomba task to being eligible for the 30-day task.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's hard to find any situation when I want to a delete a post that I don't also consider it worth a down vote.

Well, the only reason I can find is if the question is good, but there are tons of dups. But since it's full of dups, you can downvote it for lack of research.

Or if a very active question, and it has several good answers and tons of ok answers. And in the same way, if a user posts a late answer to a question that does not add anything new, then I also think it deserves a dv.

So no, I cannot think of any situation where a dv would be completely inappropriate when it deserves a delete vote.