# Is this abusing the deletion feature?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318401/how-to-alter-oracle-db-session-using-hibernate-fix-for-ora-01792-maximum-numb/46349667#46349667) by a user who probably used the unofficial Android "SOClient" app, where it's so easy to answer where you just want to comment (happened to me a couple of times). The problem is that you cannot delete the answer because of a bug.

So the user probably flagged his own answer. When I got it in review, I wanted to help for a quick deletion (since user apparently doesn't have access to a computer yet). So here's what I did:

- I downvoted so the answer had -1 points
- I refreshed the page
- I clicked "delete" (since I have 20k+ I can vote to delete at -1 for answers)
- I quickly retracted my downvote: answer has 0 points now, but 1 vote to delete.

(I didn't want downvote counting against the user, since it is taken into account for posting ban even with the answer deleted, even if this 100k user can afford that, and I didn't think it was nice.)

I don't think I'm hurting anyone by doing that in that case (my aim was to help the user deleting his post ASAP), but I unwillingly found a workaround on the "delete negative score questions" feature.

Was I right to do that? (In the hypothetical case that it wasn't flagged, I could have done the same) and is that a bug or just a feature?

(Basically [Downvote in order to be able to vote to delete. Is it acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351969/downvote-in-order-to-be-able-to-vote-to-delete-is-it-acceptable) with a twist)

Comment: I didn't want downvote counting against the user, since it counts even with the answer deleted.

Comment: It isn't an answer, and it isn't useful, so downvoting would be correct. The poster will get their reputation back once the answer is deleted as the post is still new enough yet.

Comment: It is unfortunate that it will still count against the user even if deleted, but if the user otherwise provides quality answers it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Lo and behold, the answer is now deleted.

Comment: @KevinB yes, exactly my point. Edited for clarity.

Comment: You should actually be able to vote to delete things with a score of 0, *if you do it from review* (that is, if there's a flag active on it).

Comment: @Shog9 yes, that was the case, but this "feature" can be used even if the post isn't flagged.

Comment: Yes, provided you haven't already downvoted. The 0-score feature was added to review just to make it less work in that scenario (else we'd have had to add voting too). Also, what's a "Sudosaints app"?

Comment: Why is everyone saying that the downvotes will still count against the user? The answer was posted an hour ago, no reputation losses will be kept for such an answer, only answers that have a score greater than or equal to three that have been on the site for more than 60 days will cause reputation _gains_ to be kept. I've never heard of someone keeping negative reputation changes from a deleted post.

Comment: @Shog9: android has 2 apps: the stack exchange app, good but unstable, crashes all the time, and the "stack overflow" app by "sudosaints". On that one, the delete button just doesn't work, either for comments or for answers. So if you write a big stupid turd while in the train, then you cannot stop the downvote gauntlet :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  There's two *official* apps; one called Stack Overflow, and the other by Stack Exchange.  *Both* of them are by Stack Exchange.  Any other apps are unofficial.

Comment: Well... That's unpleasant. Any chance the source is available?

Comment: @TinyGiant this isn't about rep but about post ban. Typical case: a 10 rep user posts tons of troll questions, gets a zillion downvotes, but deletes questions each time. He still keeps his rep, but may be question blocked.

Comment: It will definitely count against them for an a-ban, but the likelihood of *that* specific user hitting it, given how much reputation they have, is closer to zero.

Comment: Errr... yeah I don't see that causing a problem with one downvote to an answer (even if it did get a bunch of downvotes). The user would have to have a history of posting low quality content and not posting any good quality content for the ban.

Comment: No, I have both of these apps installed and both of them are from Stack Exchange.  I did look around and the one you mention by someone named "sudosaints" isn't available in my country.

Comment: @Makoto agreed. But let's generalize. I wasn't summoning meta to get revenge against him or to get his post deleted quicker, I was trying to help and found what I thought a loophole in the process.

Comment: The app named SOClient (by PseudoSaints) is *not* the official app; there's another app named Stack Overflow. And yet another app named Stack Exchange. Those last two are official.

Comment: @Makoto I just checked: this app is called "SoClient" actually. So yes, unofficial.

Comment: I posted a really similar question to this, but without the retracting part, the answer seems to be the same: [Downvote in order to be able to vote to delete. Is it acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351969/downvote-in-order-to-be-able-to-vote-to-delete-is-it-acceptable)

Comment: Yes, I read that good question already. But mine has the slight twist: you can vote to delete outside of review leaving a 0 score. I think it qualifies as a different question. "the answer is the same" isn't a motive for duplicate (I read that on meta some time ago :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yes this is definitely not a duplicate, I wasn't implying that it is... Just linking it in case anybody landing on this thread finds it useful, since it is closely related to this question.

Comment: no offence taken, I even included your link in my question (even though sometimes, after a few drinks, _everything_ looks like a duplicate :)). And even if you were implying that, I'm okay with that (sometimes searching prior to posting fails)

Comment: Someone really needs to add a "delete" button to the app. We regularly get moderator flags asking us to delete answers because that feature doesn't exist in the app. :-( Alternatively, if they're not going to maintain the official app anymore, it's time to remove it.

Comment: @CodyGray the catch is: there _is_ a delete button, it just doesn't work :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not abuse. The threshold for deletion was picked so that you'd *need* to do this to delete a post that hadn't been voted on; the -1 threshold actually changes to 0 if you're voting to delete from review, since there's no voting available there.

Obviously, you should only do this if the answer is actually inappropriate or harmful. The system trusts you to use your judgement on this.