# "Extremely low quality" guidance

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

The guidance on [When should I vote to delete an answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) says

> - The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
> - The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.

(The second option seems to be analogous to flagging as NAA, and I'm clear on that.)

"Extremely low quality" sounds like an even narrower requirement than "very low quality". And "very low quality" apparently is understood to mean *total garbage*. So what is "*extremely* low quality"? Even totaller garbage?

Is the bar for voting to delete an answer supposed to be stricter than the bar for flagging it, as the wording implies? Or the same? How do I calibrate "extremely low quality"?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's a little discussion about when to use the VLQ flag, but basically you should flag link-only answers as VLQ. That is it's main usage really.

Comment: @10Rep I'm not asking when to flag VLQ. I'm asking about voting to delete.

Comment: Since your delete votes don't have to be reviewed, I'd imagine it just comes down to your own judgment.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yes. But since no one is reviewing them, I have no way of knowing if I use them appropriately. Unless there is clear guidance.

Comment: yeah ihad a only code answer, that wasn't very low qualtoy and the text also excluded it from flagging it

Comment: I just vote to delete if I don't see any redeeming value even with the effort of improving the answer. The "list" is not exhaustive. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58842/213575

Comment: @Braiam That link is about deleting questions. There seems to be a lot less advice around about deleting answers.

Comment: If the quality is so low that you don't want to wait until a flag is handled but want to have it gone immediately, then it's extremely low quality.

Comment: @khelwood the advice is equivalent. As you see, deleting questions considers "answers value". Questions have no intrinsic value, only their answers. If you can't find value on the answers you can delete a question _with_ their answers.

Comment: So far I'm no more clear on where the bar is. One answer says that VTD is a lower bar than flagging; and one says that it is a higher bar. I always thought it was a lower bar (because flagging is creating work for other people; and VTD is dealing with a problem yourself using the tools available); but the wording of the advice implies it's a higher bar.

Comment: Is there a difference between "very low quality" and "extremely low quality"? Now I'm confused about when you would vote to delete without also flagging as VLQ.

Comment: *Not* a duplicate, but related: [Are blatantly wrong answers very low quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality)

Comment: @Braiam "Questions have no intrinsic value, only their answers" - strongly disagree. After all, there cannot be an answer without a question first!

Comment: @IanKemp from the point of view of deleting question, SE says so. "Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I gave [this answer on SFF Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10977/62709) a while back, but it bears some repeating

> ## Use your best judgment
>
> Unless you're an actual diamond mod, your vote isn't binding. It takes 3x 20k votes to delete answers. So, even if you get something wrong it's a delete vote that's invisible to the mere mortal (you can't even see delete votes on answers until 20k, although they do confusingly show up in the 10k deletion list). Unless 2 other 20k users agree, it will just sit there (delete votes don't age away like close votes do). But the reason they gave you the power is that you've clearly done something right for a very long time. You're a long term user. *You should know what a good answer looks like now*.

It's that last sentence you should pay attention to. Things I've voted to delete (pre-diamond) include

- NAAs that just need to go away now. Maybe it's not [red-flag gibberish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/244695) or spam, but the answer seems... iffy. Just make it go away...
- "Me too" answers. We don't need answer #1273 [explaining what a NullPointerException in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/2370483) is. Offer something new, don't offer your own spin on the same answer. Please mod flag plagiarism, though. We carry a bigger stick for that.
- Uninstructive wrong answers. Sometimes you should leave bad answers up so you can downvote as a warning to others. I'm talking about the person who posts a JavaScript answer to a C++ question. It's hard to get that across in a flag sometimes (if it looks like an answer to something it will probably fall out of the LQP review), but you only need three 20k votes to make it go away

> How do I calibrate "extremely low quality"?

The best way is the one rule you **must** follow: the answer needs a negative score. Yes, you can make it negative yourself (and [we expect you to downvote it if you're delete voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351971/2370483)), but the community can make it positive score and your power goes away (which is when mod flags are necessary). Understand that if you screw up, and people notice, they **will** come here to complain. You might be inclined to think that's a bug but that's really a feature: you'll know when you screwed up when people are complaining about it on Meta or mod flagging it to where we talk to you directly.

In most cases, it's a simple misunderstanding. A differing of opinion. It's not some dark stain on your record, it's an undelete. Don't overthink it. If that's not good enough, [we have a chat room where you can ask first](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: OK. By this advice, even a question not suitable for flagging might still be suitable for VTD; so the "extremely low quality" requirement in the guidance (in comparison to "very low quality" for flagging) is merely unfortunate wording. Is that so?

Comment: @khelwood I think the advice applied when the site was younger with lower traffic. I tend to err on the side of most 20k+ folks know what a bad answer looks like. It doesn't make every VTD legit, but you can't one-shot delete things either so the system accounts for that already.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. In reference again to specific wording, when you say "know what a bad answer looks like"—that suggests reading "extremely low quality"  as simply "bad"

Comment: @khelwood Ignore the language - it's there to discourage people from voting to delete unless they're absolutely certain the answer is trash. That was a valid concern half a decade ago when Stack Overflow wasn't overrun by help vampires, but today is different; unfortunately the language hasn't been updated, because that would be considered "unwelcoming". **The wording is nowhere near as important as your judgement** - use your downvotes and delete votes as you believe correct, without fear or favour, because your participation means you've earned them.

Answer (score 12):

I would use a delete-vote on answers if

- I don't think it adds any value, although it's a valid attempt to answer the question
- as a subject matter expert of a particular tag I think it's completely incorrect or inaccurate and would be misleading future viewers
- it's a block of code without any explanation and I think it's completely out of context of the current question.

For the above scenarios any flag should not be used.In my opinion the reasons to raise a flag are narrower than the reasons to cast a delete-vote on an answer.

Also if you want it's perfectly fine to cast a delete-vote when you have already raised a flag for the same answer.

Comment: So from your second criterion, it's reasonable to vote to delete an answer just because it's wrong? Wrong qualifies as "extremely low quality"?

Comment: "extremely low quality" is an overloaded term. I think an incorrect and misleading answer adds no value and should be voted to delete. Most of the time OP deletes it because of downvotes. So this scenario is pretty rare.

Comment: *as a subject matter expert of a particular tag I think it's completely incorrect or inaccurate and would be misleading future viewers* That's a reason to downvote, not a reason to delete. Wrong answers could be helpful if they're downvoted and people comment explaining why they're wrong - they could serve as a warning to others against dangerous or wrong solutions. I recently ran into a case where the accepted answer recommended a practice that could cause port exhaustion; I downvoted, commented with a link to the documentation saying that that was dangerous...

Comment: ... and added my own answer explaining what the OP should do instead.

Comment: Related: [Are blatantly wrong answers very low quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica it totally depends..sometimes you want to just stop at downvote..sometimes you want to go beyond and delete it..for example what is the point of keeping an answer for a question which is only in OP's imagination.It can not be flagged as well.So delete is probably the option

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica nope. I have 20k rep at another site and over there I vote the same way. For a [trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) this is a valid reason to delete useless answers. In a perfect world, it would even be a valid reason to vote delete for everyone and the only reason why system limits it to 20k (and requires consensus of three to delete) is, this is necessary to minimize mistakes (20Kers may make mistakes too, but it is much less likely that three of them all miss and  it's possible to control things because there are too few of them)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica - I see no value to the community, if I as a expert in a subject, know an answer is false.  I feel it's my duty to downvote that answer, and depending on different factors, vote to delete that answer.  The difference between Stack Exchange communities and any other Q&A community is the quality of our answers.  If I wanted to get my answers from a website, that also had inaccurate answers, I would visit my favorite technical forum on the subject.  Since we are not a discussion forum, answers that are clearly not accurate, hold no value in my eyes.

Comment: @SecurityHound I disagree - they can be very valuable if they're downvoted and people comment explaining why they're wrong. They can serve as a warning to others in case someone else was tempted to try it.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica - In my experience.  The type of answers I am voting to be deleted, are not helpful, even as a warning to other users.

Comment: @SecurityHound That would imply something other than them merely being wrong, though, because being wrong or misleading isn't a valid reason to delete it (it's a reason to downvote).

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, you see “answers” that don't actually answer the question at all. For example, the questioner asked how to do something in Python and got a reply explaining how to do it in C# or Rust. That's just literal dross that shows that *the answerer didn't bother to read the question properly.* Such answers are immensely disrespectful of the questioner, and of the whole principle of Q&A sites, and getting rid of them is the best approach. (Not-an-answer is a bit different: I'm talking about the case where the answer *is* an answer except that it completely ignores the constraints that the questioner is working under and they'd have to change everything else about what they're doing to make any kind of use of it at all.)

A retained downvoted answer is more for showing how not to do something, and there is definitely value in that. For example, if someone were to ask about synchronizing between threads in C, and an answerer were to suggest a `volatile int`, that would be a valid but wrong answer (the reasons it doesn't work are interesting and subtle) and in an ideal world the answer would be downvoted but kept so that other people can see that it is wrong.

---

Note that I do *not* mean that C# code could not appear in an answer to a Python question. There are bound to be cases where it is useful, even excluding true polyglot questions. Skill and judgement are required, not mechanical rejection. That's a great reason why deletion is generally an ability guarded by a high reputation requirement; it's a proxy for demonstrated judgement.

Comment: Minor note: Ultimately "downvoted answer kept around to show what not to do" is a bit of a workaround, since we're saying _it has value_ but also _needs to be downvoted_...kind of a contradiction. The ideal situation to my mind is an answer that explains the bad practice and why it's bad, which we can then upvote.

Answer (score 0):

> "Extremely low quality" sounds like an even narrower requirement than "very low quality". And "very low quality" apparently is understood to mean total garbage. So what is "extremely low quality"? Even totaller garbage?

IMO it is basically like this:

- Very low quality (VLQ flag) - The answer post is moreover *unlikely* to get improved, but it **can**. That's also why an edit on such a post brings the flag being marked as helpful and go away, which can be a problem if the edit didn't provided improvement to the post. If no edit is made, the moderator or the respective reviewers in the queue is given the power what to do with it if VLQ is appropriate. Otherwise the flag is declined.

  There is no absolution involved here.

  Saying: "This post is in its current status garbage, but you got the decision what to do with it. Do you think it can be edited? If not, delete it".
- Extremely low quality - The answer is really inappropriate (means it does not attempt to answer the question at all) and literally is unsalvageable. It adds no information to solve the problem and is not helpful even in the slightest.

  Saying: "This post is really bad and very unlikely to edit it to be on-topic or an attempt to answer the question. It needs to be deleted as soon as possible."

> Is the bar for voting to delete an answer supposed to be stricter than the bar for flagging it, as the wording implies? Or the same? How do I calibrate "extremely low quality"?

Depends on the context of "strictness". But basically, of course voting to delete an answer is absolute. Therefore it needs to have a very very profound reason to cast a delete vote. Flagging for VLQ is in comparison just a hint to look at it and if reviewed by others, it might get deleted. In this sense, the decision and requirement to cast a delete vote is stricter than flagging it as "very low quality" IMHO.

Comment: Every answer is salvageable though: the answerer could replace it with a good answer.

Comment: @user253751 Sure, they could also write a new answer if their previous answer was deleted. It's not like the answer bucket is getting full...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, and they could also replace the answer with a new one, thus salvaging it, and the possibility of that happening means the bad answer is salvageable, thus not unsalvageable, thus not "extremely low quality" (according to this definition) and it shouldn't be deleted in the first place.

Comment: @user253751 I understand 'unsalvageable' here in the same sense as in the Triage queue. If only the author can turn it into something useful, it's considered 'unsalvageable'.  *Every answer is salvageable* - With that reasoning we could never delete anything.

Comment: @user253751 - If an answer is deleted, the author of that deleted answer, can simply improve it then vote to have it deletion reversed.  Most answers that are not correct are also extremely low quality anyways.

Comment: @jps "With that reasoning we could never delete anything." I guess what is missing is some notion of time. If things didn't improve within some reasonable amount of time, then it's fine to delete very low quality, but you maybe don't want to delete very low quality right away, in case it does get better soon. All that delete votes or flags should basically start a timer that eventually leads to either an edit by whoever or destruction.

Comment: @user253751 At some point, you have to make a decision and you can't take both options. Of course, even an "extremely low quality" post can be salvaged, but this isn't what I meant. What I see as "extremely low quality" is something which should be deleted along the guidelines of Stack Overflow. Would you consider to not delete an abusive post just because the potential is there to make it a good post? - Also in such case if the answer is really really turned in a good and helpful answer (which is rarely the case) the vote to delete should be retracted, but...

Comment: ...discussing about the retracting feature for the vote to delete is not the focus of this post.