# Should I remove an answered question that was not quite what I meant to ask?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54636818/2160877) about karate and unsurprisingly the author of karate answered.

The answer did not work for me, to which I commented pointing out the difference to my needs and I made an update to the question to make it more clear.

Then I received an invitation to open a new question for my new issue and accept the current answer (currently this comment seems deleted).
From my point of view, I had one specific issue that I couldn't solve myself, so two questions were not needed, but still I opened a [new one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54647176/2160877).
This time the answer was exactly what I was looking for, so I gladly accepted it and upvoted it.

Meanwhile I received another invitation to accept the answer to the previous question.

What I would do is to delete the old question, since apparently it was not clear enough and the answer is something that I had managed to find already by reading the docs.

While I really admire what the author of karate has done implementing it and documenting it, as well as being available to answer questions
 about it on Stack Overflow, I don't feel that it is the right thing to leave my old question and accept the answer to it.
Apparently I am in doubt what really is the right thing to be done, since I assume *the question may turn out helpful for others*...

So should I revert my update to the old question and accept the answer, or remove the question? Why?

Comment: I would just delete the old question, alternatively the old one could be closed as a duplicate of the new one, you certainly shouldn't be expected to accept an answer you're not happy with

Comment: imo, If the question was unclear, and then the edit changed the question meaning, then *he* can edit to change his answer. It's him that answered an unclear question. It's not like you edited to invalidate a answer.

Comment: Wait... The author of Karate?  *The author of Karate??* ***BRUCE FRIGGEN LEE???***

Comment: Bruce Lee was Kung Fu, @Will. Pat Morita is the author of Karate.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ah, wax off willya?

Comment: @yagmoth555 Yes, this is what I expected as well. And now since I cannot delete the question I can either leave it like it is or update my question so that it fits the answer... Well, in the latter case it will no longer be my question.

Comment: @helleye My point was more, ask **him** to update his answer to fit your question. He should had not asked you to post another question in the first place IMO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not accept an answer to your question unless it works for you or solves your problem. That is the function of the green checkmark: to tell other users "this worked for OP". Separately, if the answer is or could be *useful* to you or other readers, then it merits an upvote.

Likewise, it's considered improper to demand or insist that an asker accept your answer. Comments such as this are usually deleted when flagged as no longer needed.

As for deleting the original question, it's up to you to decide whether you want to do so, but keep in mind you cannot delete your own question if there is an accepted answer, an upvoted answer, or more than one answer currently attached to it.

Comment: Re: *"**you cannot delete your own question if there is** an accepted answer, **an upvoted answer**, or more than one answer currently attached to it"*, if OP was the upvoter of the answer it can be edited and then the upvote removed and the post deleted

Comment: @NickA I was not the upvoter, but I guess I can downvote it and then delete it, if that will be the direction I will be heading at.

Comment: @helleye I don't know if that would work, it would still be upvoted, it would just have a score of 0 (it has multiple upvotes now regardless)

Comment: @helleye It's probably of limited impact in this case, but keep in mind that [cleanup by downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307010/2756409) is expressly forbidden.

Comment: @TylerH Arguably the answer isn't helpful to OP and so they could just be downvoted as unhelpful :P doesn't have to be for the cleanup directly (although I do agree with you)

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve the dilemma. I totally changed my question so I could accept the answer. This way it could be useful for others searching for that solution. Since the answer was not useful to me I decided to downvote it.

Comment: @helleye Glad you were able to come to a resolution; do note that in some cases (e.g. when you have answers addressing your question as it is), it's inappropriate to edit your question significantly such that it is, in essence, asking a different question (in other words, you can't make changes to your question that would totally invalidate existing answers as that's not fair to the answerers or future readers).

Comment: @TylerH Yes, I am aware of that and that is why it was hard for me to IMHO completely change the question, but I hope it will be helpful for the community.